# Discrete logarithm using python

Tags: python, logarithm

I have a set of logarithm which are L1, L2 and L3 which I have retrieved it from the paper "An Ultra-secure Router-to-router Spontaneous Key Exchange System", 2015:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

And this is the result for the equations:

[image]

Given the value of alpha=5, x=15 and p=97. After I implement it in Python, I got the wrong result, which is not same in the result in the table.

This is the code:

```
a=5
x=15
p=97
i1=0.958478
i2=4.238835

L1=pow(a,x+i1)%p
L2=pow(a,x+i1+i2)%p
L3=pow(a,x+i2)%p

print ("L1",L1)
print ("L2",L2)
print ("L3",L3)
```

And this is the results that I've got:

```
L1 55.596893310546875
L2 2.15625
L3 68.87890625
```

Please help me to identify the errors in my code. Thank you.

Comment: @abarnert, unfortunately OP is not doing with integer, so OP can't use 3 args `pow`.

Comment: I would trust python to compute correctly more than "these are the values I should get.": where does this table come from and why should you trust it? There's not much code here just simple computations so not much room for getting any logic wrong...

Comment: use ** operator maybe

Comment: I _wouldn't_ trust Python to compute these values. `5**97` is going to be big enough that rounding to the nearest IEEE float should have an error somewhere on the order of 1 or 2 digits. So when you `% 97` the result, you're getting mostly error. That back-of-the-envelope calculation could be off a few digits in either direction, but the point is, I certainly wouldn't just assume that float rounding isn't going to be hugely relevant here.

Comment: If that _is_ the issue, switching to `decimal.Decimal` instead of `float` and specifying a high enough precision would fix things. Of course if that isn't the issue, if the OP just looked up the wrong line in a table or something… well, trying `Decimal` would be a quick way to rule that out.

Comment: OK, it looks like I was a tiny bit off—the error is 3 digits to the right of the decimal point, not 1 to the left. [See Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(5%5E15.958478)+mod+97), which is easier to link to than code running with `Decimal`.

Comment: @abarnert, if I do
`K=pow(a,x)%p`
I get the result of 46

Comment: @Afir So how is that relevant here?

Comment: @abarnert The wrong answer happens when I add the sign of `+`. For example `L1=pow(a,x+i1)%p`. I don't have any idea why it happen. Is there any alternative code to do it?

Comment: Your calculation is right (or close enough—it should be 55.59702001110441972784085691044893956988776136925821958091...). So either you've got something wrong in reading the paper, or the paper is wrong.

Comment: The paper may not using the exact number (0.958478), take a look
 on http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+y+%3D+(5%5Ex)+mod+97+from+x+%3D+15.958478+to+15.958479 , the value variate a lot even just from `15.958478` to `15.958479`. If the author use a random seed generator to produce a float value, it should not be 6 digit and thus the value shown is rounded off already.